# ELB (Application) is not redirecting http requests to Jira EC2 added to ASG

Tags: amazon-web-services, jira

I have defined the instance port (8080) on target group, configured target group to use port 8080. then pointed ELB's port 80 listener to the target group name. but it doesn't seem to work for me?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Jira is running fine in the EC2 and allow to reach internet (IGW) at VPC level. There is a few things you can check:

1. Check if the instance is in `healthy` status under the target group
2. Check if the security group for ALB allow port 80 for inbound and allow port 8080 for outbound
3. Check if the security group for the EC2 instance allow port 8080 from ELB

Comment: Thanks for your reply, 1- instance is not healthy unless I change the success code from 200 to 302. 2- SG for ALB allows port 80, 3- SG for EC2 allows port 8080

Comment: One more thing to add, when I try to http call instance *.*.*.*:8080 jira is working. but when I try to call ALB DNS it is not working. obviously as I mentioned, Target is showing instance as unhealthy.

Comment: 1. you need to make sure the health check is successful, you can refer to AWS document and find which is the suitable method for your target to response correctly (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html). If your target/endpoint will return `302` to the healthcheck then you can add `302` to the `Success Codes` under the Health Checks tab.

ALB DNS not working is due to no target is healthy for it to route the traffic, so if you fix the healthcheck, it should go through.

Comment: Thank you verymuch. found the issue and solved it. it was the on-prem FW blocking http requests to ELB endpoint.